# SQL NOT EXISTS sub query not functioning as expected

Tags: sql, subquery, not-exists

I have an issue where I am using a query to filter my results based on the lead time of an article. The confusing part for me is there is a sub section of that where i need to filter certain articles based on lead time and the country of origin.  I am trying to do this using a `NOT EXISTS`statement in side of `WHERE` but the results don't seem to be what I would expect.  For example all articles with a country of origin of HONDURAS and a lead time of 90 should not return any results with a so_conf_del_date of after 2/15/19...however in the results I get many results of dates well into march which should be excluded from what I can see.  Thought I would get a different set of eyes on it as I really don't use not exists a ton. thanks.

UPDATE: changing to NOT IN from NOT EXISTS and updated the correlation.  Note also the subquery performs exactly as it should so not sure why I am getting results back outside of the range

Query UPDATED:

```
/* What to do about multiple COO's in ONE RANGE? ...join on order ORDER_ITEM.SEASONAL_INDICATOR? */
/* Use CASE WHEN in subquery to JOIN outerquery on vw_order_item.seasonal_indicator = OneRange_NAM.SEASON */
/* Assumption is being made that 'seasonal indicator' in vw_order_item would align with 'season' and thus COO in OneRange */
/* Added Date/LeadTime Parameters */
/* Use 'Planned Delivery Time'...this includes lead time and delivery time? */
/* Right join to ONE RANGE */
/* ARUN has no fully unallocated quantities - YES IT DOES */
/* 11/12/18 - replaced RDD with CDD */

SELECT kd.business_segment_desc, 
       q0.plant_code,
       q0.req_cat AS 'requirement_category',
       m.[department], 
       q0.commission_code_id,
       aa.LeadTime,
       q0.so_conf_del_date, 
       q0.valid_to_date,
       q0.sales_order_number, 
       q0.sales_order_item_number,
       q0.sold_to, 
       q0.bill_to,
       m.working_number,
       q0.material,
       m.[description],
       q0.open_quantity,
       q0.allocated_quantity,
       q0.unallocated_quantity,
       q0.percent_unallocated,
       aa.ActivationStatus AS 'global status',
       m.ib_lock,
       o.country_of_origin

FROM   pdx_sap_user..vw_mm_material m
JOIN   pdx_sap_user..vw_kd_business_segment kd ON m.business_segment_code = kd.business_segment_code
JOIN   asagdwpdx_prod..ArticleNumbers aa ON m.material = aa.ArticleNumber
JOIN   adi_user_maintained..VW_ONERange_NAM o ON     m.material = o.article 
                                              AND    aa.ArticleNumber = o.Article
JOIN

(SELECT i.plant_code, 
       h.commission_code_id, 
       a.so_conf_del_date,
       h.valid_to_date,
       i.sales_order_number, 
       i.sales_order_item_number,
       h.sold_to,
       h.bill_to,
       i.material,
       i.open_quantity,
      ((i.open_quantity) - SUM(a.quantity)) AS 'allocated_quantity',
     SUM(a.quantity) AS 'unallocated_quantity',
       a.req_cat,
       ROUND(SUM(a.quantity)/(i.open_quantity),2) AS 'percent_unallocated',
       SUM(a.quantity) AS 'arun_allocated_qty',
       CASE 
         WHEN i.seasonal_indicator = '18S' 
         THEN 'SS2018' 
         WHEN i.seasonal_indicator = '18F'
         THEN 'FW2018'
         WHEN i.seasonal_indicator = '19S' 
         THEN 'SS2019' 
         WHEN i.seasonal_indicator = '19F' 
         THEN 'FW2019'
         ELSE 'NO SEASON'
       END AS 'seasonal_indicator'

FROM   pdx_sap_user..vw_order_item i 
JOIN  pdx_sap_user..vw_order_header h ON i.sales_order_number = h.sales_order_number 
JOIN   pdx_sap_user..vw_arun_norm_new a ON i.sales_order_number = a.sales_order_number 
AND    i.sales_order_item_number = a.sales_order_item_number


WHERE  i.open_quantity > 0
AND    h.commission_code_id = 'B'
AND    a.stock_type = 'A'

GROUP BY i.plant_code, 
         h.commission_code_id, 
         a.so_conf_del_date,
         h.valid_to_date,
         i.sales_order_number, 
         i.sales_order_item_number,
         h.sold_to,
         h.bill_to,
         i.material,
         i.open_quantity,
         a.req_cat,
         i.unallocated_quantity,
         i.seasonal_indicator

HAVING SUM((a.quantity)/i.open_quantity) > .5) q0 ON m.material = q0.material 
                                                  AND q0.seasonal_indicator = o.season

WHERE    aa.LeadTime = '30'
AND      q0.so_conf_del_date < '01/15/2019'
OR       aa.LeadTime = '45'
AND      q0.so_conf_del_date < '02/01/2019'
OR       aa.LeadTime = '60'
AND      q0.so_conf_del_date < '02/15/2019'
OR       aa.LeadTime = '75'
AND      q0.so_conf_del_date < '03/01/2019'
OR       aa.LeadTime = '90'
AND      q0.so_conf_del_date < '03/15/2019'
OR       aa.LeadTime = '105'
AND      q0.so_conf_del_date < '04/01/2019'
OR       aa.LeadTime = '120'
AND      q0.so_conf_del_date < '04/15/2019'
OR       aa.LeadTime = '135'
AND      q0.so_conf_del_date < '05/01/2019'

AND      q0.sales_order_number NOT IN ( SELECT   q01.sales_order_number

                                        FROM   pdx_sap_user..vw_order_item q01
                                        JOIN   pdx_sap_user..vw_arun_norm_new a1 ON q01.sales_order_number = a1.sales_order_number 
                                        AND    q01.sales_order_item_number = a1.sales_order_item_number
                                        JOIN   asagdwpdx_prod..ArticleNumbers aa1 ON q01.material = aa1.ArticleNumber
                                        JOIN   adi_user_maintained..VW_ONERange_NAM o1 ON q01.material = o1.article 

WHERE  
(
aa1.LeadTime = '30'
AND    o1.country_of_origin IN ('EL SALVADOR','HONDURAS','MEXICO','U S A' ,'GUATEMALA')
AND    a1.so_conf_del_date > '12/15/2018'
)
OR     
(
aa1.LeadTime = '45' 
AND    o1.country_of_origin IN ('EL SALVADOR','HONDURAS','MEXICO','U S A' ,'GUATEMALA')
AND    a1.so_conf_del_date > '01/01/2019'
)
OR     
(
aa1.LeadTime = '60' 
AND    o1.country_of_origin IN ('EL SALVADOR','HONDURAS','MEXICO','U S A' ,'GUATEMALA')
AND    a1.so_conf_del_date > '01/15/2019'
)
OR     
(
aa1.LeadTime = '75' 
AND    o1.country_of_origin IN ('EL SALVADOR','HONDURAS','MEXICO','U S A' ,'GUATEMALA')
AND    a1.so_conf_del_date > '02/01/2019'
)
OR     
(
aa1.LeadTime = '90' 
AND    o1.country_of_origin IN ('EL SALVADOR','HONDURAS','MEXICO','U S A' ,'GUATEMALA')
AND    a1.so_conf_del_date > '02/15/2019'
)
OR     
(
aa1.LeadTime = '90' 
AND    o1.country_of_origin IN ('EL SALVADOR','HONDURAS','MEXICO','U S A' ,'GUATEMALA')
AND    a1.so_conf_del_date > '03/01/2019'
)
OR     
(
aa1.LeadTime = '105' 
AND    o1.country_of_origin IN ('EL SALVADOR','HONDURAS','MEXICO','U S A' ,'GUATEMALA')
AND    a1.so_conf_del_date > '03/15/2019'
)
AND    q0.sales_order_number = q01.sales_order_number
AND    aa.LeadTime = aa1.LeadTime
AND    q0.so_conf_del_date = a1.so_conf_del_date
AND    o.Country_of_Origin = o1.Country_of_Origin)

GROUP BY kd.business_segment_desc, 
         q0.plant_code,
         q0.req_cat,
         m.[department], 
         q0.commission_code_id,
         aa.LeadTime,
         q0.so_conf_del_date, 
         q0.valid_to_date,
         q0.sales_order_number, 
         q0.sales_order_item_number,
         q0.sold_to, 
         q0.bill_to,
         m.working_number,
         q0.material,
         m.[description],
         q0.open_quantity,
         q0.allocated_quantity,
         q0.unallocated_quantity,
         q0.percent_unallocated,
         aa.ActivationStatus,
         m.ib_lock,
         o.country_of_origin

ORDER BY q0.sales_order_number DESC;
```

WORKING VERSION:

```
/* What to do about multiple COO's in ONE RANGE? ...join on order ORDER_ITEM.SEASONAL_INDICATOR? */
/* Use CASE WHEN in subquery to JOIN outerquery on vw_order_item.seasonal_indicator = OneRange_NAM.SEASON */
/* Assumption is being made that 'seasonal indicator' in vw_order_item would align with 'season' and thus COO in OneRange */
/* Added Date/LeadTime Parameters */
/* Use 'Planned Delivery Time'...this includes lead time and delivery time? */
/* Right join to ONE RANGE */
/* ARUN has no fully unallocated quantities - YES IT DOES */
/* 11/12/18 - replaced RDD with CDD */

SELECT kd.business_segment_desc, 
       q0.plant_code,
       q0.req_cat AS 'requirement_category',
       m.[department], 
       q0.commission_code_id,
       aa.LeadTime,
       q0.so_conf_del_date, 
       q0.valid_to_date,
       q0.sales_order_number, 
       q0.sales_order_item_number,
       q0.sold_to, 
       q0.bill_to,
       m.working_number,
       q0.material,
       m.[description],
       q0.open_quantity,
       q0.allocated_quantity,
       q0.unallocated_quantity,
       q0.percent_unallocated,
       aa.ActivationStatus AS 'global status',
       m.ib_lock,
       o.country_of_origin

FROM   pdx_sap_user..vw_mm_material m
JOIN   pdx_sap_user..vw_kd_business_segment kd ON m.business_segment_code = kd.business_segment_code
JOIN   asagdwpdx_prod..ArticleNumbers aa ON m.material = aa.ArticleNumber
JOIN   adi_user_maintained..VW_ONERange_NAM o ON     m.material = o.article 
                                              AND    aa.ArticleNumber = o.Article
JOIN

(SELECT i.plant_code, 
       h.commission_code_id, 
       a.so_conf_del_date,
       h.valid_to_date,
       i.sales_order_number, 
       i.sales_order_item_number,
       h.sold_to,
       h.bill_to,
       i.material,
       i.open_quantity,
      ((i.open_quantity) - SUM(a.quantity)) AS 'allocated_quantity',
     SUM(a.quantity) AS 'unallocated_quantity',
       a.req_cat,
       ROUND(SUM(a.quantity)/(i.open_quantity),2) AS 'percent_unallocated',
       SUM(a.quantity) AS 'arun_allocated_qty',
       CASE 
         WHEN i.seasonal_indicator = '18S' 
         THEN 'SS2018' 
         WHEN i.seasonal_indicator = '18F'
         THEN 'FW2018'
         WHEN i.seasonal_indicator = '19S' 
         THEN 'SS2019' 
         WHEN i.seasonal_indicator = '19F' 
         THEN 'FW2019'
         ELSE 'NO SEASON'
       END AS 'seasonal_indicator'

FROM   pdx_sap_user..vw_order_item i 
JOIN  pdx_sap_user..vw_order_header h ON i.sales_order_number = h.sales_order_number 
JOIN   pdx_sap_user..vw_arun_norm_new a ON i.sales_order_number = a.sales_order_number 
AND    i.sales_order_item_number = a.sales_order_item_number


WHERE  i.open_quantity > 0
AND    h.commission_code_id = 'B'
AND    a.stock_type = 'A'
AND    i.sales_order_number NOT IN (SELECT   q01.sales_order_number

                                        FROM   pdx_sap_user..vw_order_item q01
                                        JOIN   pdx_sap_user..vw_arun_norm_new a1 ON q01.sales_order_number = a1.sales_order_number 
                                        AND    q01.sales_order_item_number = a1.sales_order_item_number
                                        JOIN   asagdwpdx_prod..ArticleNumbers aa1 ON q01.material = aa1.ArticleNumber
                                        JOIN   adi_user_maintained..VW_ONERange_NAM o1 ON q01.material = o1.article 

WHERE  
(
aa1.LeadTime = '30'
AND    o1.country_of_origin IN ('EL SALVADOR','HONDURAS','MEXICO','U S A' ,'GUATEMALA')
AND    a1.so_conf_del_date > '12/15/2018'
)
OR     
(
aa1.LeadTime = '45' 
AND    o1.country_of_origin IN ('EL SALVADOR','HONDURAS','MEXICO','U S A' ,'GUATEMALA')
AND    a1.so_conf_del_date > '01/01/2019'
)
OR     
(
aa1.LeadTime = '60' 
AND    o1.country_of_origin IN ('EL SALVADOR','HONDURAS','MEXICO','U S A' ,'GUATEMALA')
AND    a1.so_conf_del_date > '01/15/2019'
)
OR     
(
aa1.LeadTime = '75' 
AND    o1.country_of_origin IN ('EL SALVADOR','HONDURAS','MEXICO','U S A' ,'GUATEMALA')
AND    a1.so_conf_del_date > '02/01/2019'
)
OR     
(
aa1.LeadTime = '90' 
AND    o1.country_of_origin IN ('EL SALVADOR','HONDURAS','MEXICO','U S A' ,'GUATEMALA')
AND    a1.so_conf_del_date > '02/15/2019'
)
OR     
(
aa1.LeadTime = '90' 
AND    o1.country_of_origin IN ('EL SALVADOR','HONDURAS','MEXICO','U S A' ,'GUATEMALA')
AND    a1.so_conf_del_date > '03/01/2019'
)
OR     
(
aa1.LeadTime = '105' 
AND    o1.country_of_origin IN ('EL SALVADOR','HONDURAS','MEXICO','U S A' ,'GUATEMALA')
AND    a1.so_conf_del_date > '03/15/2019'
)
AND    q01.sales_order_number = i.sales_order_number)

GROUP BY i.plant_code, 
         h.commission_code_id, 
         a.so_conf_del_date,
         h.valid_to_date,
         i.sales_order_number, 
         i.sales_order_item_number,
         h.sold_to,
         h.bill_to,
         i.material,
         i.open_quantity,
         a.req_cat,
         i.unallocated_quantity,
         i.seasonal_indicator

HAVING SUM((a.quantity)/i.open_quantity) > .5) q0 ON m.material = q0.material 
                                                  AND q0.seasonal_indicator = o.season

WHERE    aa.LeadTime = '30'
AND      q0.so_conf_del_date < '01/15/2019'
OR       aa.LeadTime = '45'
AND      q0.so_conf_del_date < '02/01/2019'
OR       aa.LeadTime = '60'
AND      q0.so_conf_del_date < '02/15/2019'
OR       aa.LeadTime = '75'
AND      q0.so_conf_del_date < '03/01/2019'
OR       aa.LeadTime = '90'
AND      q0.so_conf_del_date < '03/15/2019'
OR       aa.LeadTime = '105'
AND      q0.so_conf_del_date < '04/01/2019'
OR       aa.LeadTime = '120'
AND      q0.so_conf_del_date < '04/15/2019'
OR       aa.LeadTime = '135'
AND      q0.so_conf_del_date < '05/01/2019'

GROUP BY kd.business_segment_desc, 
         q0.plant_code,
         q0.req_cat,
         m.[department], 
         q0.commission_code_id,
         aa.LeadTime,
         q0.so_conf_del_date, 
         q0.valid_to_date,
         q0.sales_order_number, 
         q0.sales_order_item_number,
         q0.sold_to, 
         q0.bill_to,
         m.working_number,
         q0.material,
         m.[description],
         q0.open_quantity,
         q0.allocated_quantity,
         q0.unallocated_quantity,
         q0.percent_unallocated,
         aa.ActivationStatus,
         m.ib_lock,
         o.country_of_origin

ORDER BY q0.sales_order_number DESC
```

Comment: At a guess.... you need more brackets to define the `OR` boolean expressions properly. You have an `OR` (or probably many) which is short circuiting the entire boolean expression.

Comment: seems odd because the outer statement doing the same thing on all the other lines works perfect...wondering if it is something to do with the IN statement or maybe how it is connected to the outer query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your OR is short circuiting. For example, look at this piece:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE  aa1.LeadTime = '30'
AND    o1.country_of_origin IN ('EL SALVADOR','HONDURAS','MEXICO','U S A' ,'GUATEMALA')
AND    a1.so_conf_del_date > '12/15/2018'
OR     aa1.LeadTime = '45'
```

Returns all records with `aa1.LeadTime = '45'` regardless of the other conditions.

I guess you mean this:

```
WHERE  
(
aa1.LeadTime = '30'
AND    o1.country_of_origin IN ('EL SALVADOR','HONDURAS','MEXICO','U S A' ,'GUATEMALA')
AND    a1.so_conf_del_date > '12/15/2018'
)
OR     
(
aa1.LeadTime = '45' 
AND    o1.country_of_origin IN ('EL SALVADOR','HONDURAS','MEXICO','U S A' ,'GUATEMALA')
AND    a1.so_conf_del_date > '01/01/2019'
)
OR     
(
aa1.LeadTime = '60' 
AND    o1.country_of_origin IN ('EL SALVADOR','HONDURAS','MEXICO','U S A' ,'GUATEMALA')
AND    a1.so_conf_del_date > '01/15/2019'
)
....
....
```

which is a *very* different expression.

Comment: ah thanks for that clarification! I assumed for some reason the execution order restarted at each OR, I am going to give that a go!

Comment: still returning results outside of the range - for example lead time of 45 is returning dates ahead of 1/1/2019...will keep digging. thanks.

Comment: your point was definitely correct - to stop getting the results outside of my range i moved the NOT IN to inside the JOIN on q0 and it seemed to solve the issue.  Trying to fully understand why.  Posted the final code above.